# Cannot query across many-to-many for property (NestJS / TypeORM)

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm struggling with queries over many-to-many relation using typeorm.
I have two entities: users and groups, both having many-to-many relations to each other.
User entity has this:

```
  @ManyToMany(() => Group, group => group.users)
  @JoinTable()
  groups: Group[];
```

Group entity has this:

```
  @ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.groups)
  users: User[];
```

I want to get all groups of a specified user, that have a certain value. In my case, I want all groups for user X that have `ishidden = false`. So I tried diffentent things, but none work...

```
  const groups = this.groupRepository.find({
      relations: ['users'],
      where: {
        ishidden: false,
        users: {
          id: user.id
        }
      }
    });
```

I was really hoping that it would work this way, but it just throws `Cannot query across many-to-many for property users`. Other approaches with querybuilder also didnt work :-(

I can't be that hard the query a related table, can it? I'm coming from the C# world, so maybe I'm just doing it wrong ;-)

Comment: Can you send the full entities? I'm trying to figure out how is the structure on the is hidden

Comment: Did you find a solution using the repositoryAPI ?

Comment: Yes. Just upgrade to "typeorm": "^0.3.7" and "@nestjs/typeorm": "~8.1.4" or "8.1.4", This makes a Many-To-Many query exactly as you asked on the question. @Bruno

Answer (score 3):

Recently faced a similar problem(nestjs + ts + typeorm). Try something like this:

```js
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';

// some code
constructor(private connection: Connection) {}
// some code

await this.connection
  .getRepository(Group) // group entity
  .createQueryBuilder('groups') // table name
  .leftJoin('groups.users', 'users') // join group table and user table
  .where('ishidden = false AND users.id = :userId ', {
    userId: userId,
  })
  .getMany();
```

Comment: Please is there a direct way to make the query with the `.find` function? @Maksim

Comment: @Vixson in case we have a many-to-many relation, I use this method. In [docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options) you can find this method:
`userRepository.find({select: ["firstName", "lastName"], relations: ["profile", "photos", "videos"], where: { firstName: "Timber", lastName: "Saw", profile: { userName: "tshaw"}}}`
But it doesn't work for many-to-many relations

Comment: Ok thank @Maksim I'll make use of the `createQueryBuilder` method for the main time while I go through the `find` method deeply.

I believe the `createQueryBuilder` is more precise.

Thanks